# Uppercase every first English letter if it isn't uppercased already, with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, capitalization, vscode-snippets

I have a plain text document I process with Visual Studio Code, with about 1,000 lines.
Each line contains a sentence that starts with an English letter.

- No special characters are used as a starting character.
- In some sentences, the first letter is uppercased,
- In some other sentences, the first letter is lowercased.

I desire to uppercase every first English letter if it isn't uppercased already, with regex.

### What I have tried:

**Search (match):**

```
^[a-z]*
```

**Replace with:**

```
[A-Z]*
```

**Result:**

```
A-Z*U+0020 sentence
```

> A-Z* sentence

**To clarify, I got:**

`A-Z*` + `U+0020` (a whitespace character), at the start of each line, in all about 1,000 lines.

### My question

How could I uppercase every first English letter that isn't uppercased already, with regex?

Comment: try this select all using `crtl + A`, then `ctrl + shift + P` then Type in the command  title (Transform to Title case)

Comment: Case conversion isn't supported in most regex flavors, and among those that do support it, it's done in various different ways. With the PCRE engine, you can match `^([a-z])` and replace with `\U\1`. Read up more about it here https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html

Comment: You can create a *dictionary* at the bottom of your file with a keyword prepending it and create your replacement relationships there, capturing the replacement values into a capture group and replacing it accordingly. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/Xlysct/1) demonstration. When you're done, simply remove the dictionary.

Comment: @Sha it opened a list in which I found the option "transform to uppercase" --- this function uppercased all letters whatsoever which is of course different than my desired outcome. I thank you for the suggestion anyway and glad to know this list for the first time.

Comment: @CAustin I have WSL in my Windows 10 home; perhaps Bash or some other shell can help, from your experience? Thanks anyway,

Comment: @ctwheels honestly, I thought about matching letter by letter from a letter dictionary but I believe there should be a more efficient way --- perhaps by some shell(Bash/Zsh/whatever); GNU/Linux shell text-processing tools can have powerful functions in them, perhaps that's the only "functional" solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will become simpler because vscode has added support for the `\u` modifier - which would uppercase the following character in the replace string.

Also your original query `^[a-z]*` is a problem because it uses the `*` so it does match the empty string.  You can simply use this:

`^([a-z])`

Replace with `\u$1` the `\u` makes what follows uppercase, which in your case is only one letter.

See https://regex101.com/r/PDWaco/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension on vs code. [image]

```
Name: change-case
Id: wmaurer.change-case
Description: Quickly change the case (camelCase, CONSTANT_CASE, snake_case, etc) of the current selection or current word
Version: 1.0.0
Publisher: wmaurer
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wmaurer.change-case
```

1. install extension `change-case`
2. select your all text by `ctrl + A`
3. open command palette by `ctrl + shift + P`
4. type `Change Case upperFirst` and hit enter.

It will convert your document 1st letter to upper case.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I  tried that extension, it does have a bug in that if there are empty lines at the beginning of the file it deletes all of them.